# Is it ok to deploy today with Wildfly8 waiting for the next JBoss EAP to be released?

Tags: jboss, java-8, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm about to start working on a project to be deployed later this year and would like to use JDK8. We use JBoss EAP for production but the latest JBoss EAP, 6.2 (based on JBoss AS 7.3) does not yet support it.

From a compatibility perspective, is it ok to start deploying in Wildfly8 now (which supports JDK8) with the expectation that later this year the corresponding EAP will come out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your application to be fair.
WildFly 8 support EE7 and EAP6 EE6, so it is up to you to decide what level of Java EE you need/want.

In future WildFly will be base for EAP7, which version of WildFly will depend on what is available at the time when "productivization" will begin.

As for Java 8 support goes, EAP 6.3 runs on Java 8, currently it is at Beta release which you can grab from http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads/ with GA release coming soon.

Comment: JBoss EAP 6.3.3 supports Java 8 now.